How can I correctly rotating/align a coarse-grained lipid with a reference using scipy?
I am trying to align the vector passing through all points of a coarse-grained representation of a lipid molecule with that of another.
This representation of a lipid molecule has 12 coarse-grained beads, so the array representing it is 12x3 for the xyz coordinates of each bead.
A coarse grained lipid for reference:

If I have one called DOPC_upper (representing a DOPC lipid facing upwards) and another called DOPC_lower (facing downwards), I run the scipy rotation function:
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R

rot, _ = R.align_vectors(DOPC_upper, DOPC_lower)

rot.apply(DOPC_lower)

And expect to find the coordinates of this lower lipid facing upward as if it were on the upper leaflet.
What I get instead is a lipid that is horizontal, seemingly meeting the two vectors halfway.
What am I missing here?
EDIT:
as requested, print(DOPC_upper):
array([[1.332, 1.029, 2.917],
       [1.39 , 0.697, 2.67 ],
       [1.253, 0.648, 2.363],
       [1.318, 0.643, 2.117],
       [0.867, 0.878, 2.147],
       [0.6  , 1.198, 1.858],
       [0.869, 1.481, 1.556],
       [0.873, 1.536, 1.08 ],
       [0.962, 0.469, 1.9  ],
       [0.638, 0.387, 1.486],
       [0.658, 0.398, 1.051],
       [0.68 , 0.673, 0.749]])

and DOPC_lower:
array([[1.328, 1.072, 0.738],
       [0.969, 0.996, 0.933],
       [0.849, 0.994, 1.354],
       [0.948, 1.235, 1.535],
       [0.859, 0.769, 1.76 ],
       [1.017, 0.551, 2.117],
       [1.176, 0.81 , 2.444],
       [1.433, 1.041, 2.699],
       [0.791, 1.289, 1.998],
       [0.639, 1.265, 2.464],
       [0.938, 1.123, 2.806],
       [1.058, 0.851, 3.157]])

I managed to get the rotation vector by making individual vectors through each by taking the first and last coordinate, but finding one that best represents all points on the molecule would be even better.

Can you run print(DOPC_upper) and print(DOPC_lower), and edit your question to include the output?

@NickODell Sorry for the delayed reply and thanks for your comment, the post has been edited!

Two thoughts: 1) These points don't seem to be centered on 0,0,0. Keep in mind that when it's computing the rotation, it is rotating the points around 0,0,0. 2) Are the points in the same order in both arrays? That is important for using align_vectors().
